# MongoDB aggregation running two group operations at once

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-aggregation

Given:

A collection where I have some columns where for two of them I want to get all used values

Currently I'm doing two aggregations like below (simplified)

```
db['myCollection'].aggregate(
  [{$group: {"_id":"$firstCol"}}  ]
);
```

and

```
db['myCollection'].aggregate(
  [{$group: {"_id":"$secondCol"}}  ]
);
```

But it feels like a waste of resources to run two aggregations. Is there a way to get both grouped results at once?

I thought about combining them and later on split it in code.

Comment: It is   unclear what you are asking here. Do you want to group by "firstCol" and "secondCol"? Can you provide sample document with the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like so with the aid of the [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator

```
db['myCollection'].aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            col1: {
                $addToSet: "$firstCol"
            },
            col2: {
                $addToSet: "$secondCol"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

If you have indexes on the target fields then I would choose separate calls with [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/), as this can take advantage of those and probably result in less workload / faster execution times.

```
db[myCollection].distinct('firstCol')
```

Comment: @BoasEnkler Did this answer help or do you need something different?